# How do I dynamically set the value of a input when I load the html after a click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, handlebars.js

So I have a bunch of p elements that call the redo function on click.

As you can see, I load the quest[q] template onto the .form div when it gets clicked. Each of these templates that can be loaded were previously submitted forms that sent the value to an object.

When the P element gets clicked, the idea is to rerender the form that gives the user the ability to modify the value in the object.

Right now I am just hard coding examples as you can see by setting the value of income id (which is the id of the input on template that I am rendering onto the .form div).

However this isnt working, so when the template is rerender, the value in the input blank.

Can anyone help me figure out so as to how I can get the value of the input to show the previously submitted value?

```
function redo(q,elem){

    q=Number(q);
    console.log(q);
    if(q+1 != iterator){

    $('.form').load(quest[q]); 
    iterator=q+1;


    }
     var income = document.getElementById('income');
    income.value=1;   (this will be objectname.property);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with an example solution https://jsfiddle.net/1nxv2qhr/1/

```js
$('p').click(function(){
  $("#income").text("This is a test message");
  $('#div1').html("This is a test message");
  $('#textbox1').val("This is a test message");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click Me!!!</p>

<p id="income"></p>
<div id="div1"></div>
<input type="text" id="textbox1" />
```

For, setting the value to an element like (`paragraph`, `div`), please use `.html` or `.text` and for `input textbox` use `.val`

Hope this will help you to achieve solution.

Comment: Cant believe how much I over thought this. However, it only works if you hardcode a value. I am doing $("#id).val(object.prop); and it isnt working.

Comment: @Aaron... What problem you are facing now? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Can you create a **jsfiddle** with your current code.

Comment: @Aaron... I made it working https://jsfiddle.net/3b1n1dpf/3/ . You need to add value to an `input` `textbox` as text not as a number.

Comment: I need it to be a number =/ It also doesnt work in my code

Comment: So the error I discovered is that on the first click, the value will not be rendered. Once I click the text again the proper value then does render. I think this has something to do with the fact that I am rendering a html file on the page and the val code happens before the full rendering gets to happen. Going to try fixing this with promises